# Obter dados do SQL para o Select

Tags: php, sql

um fórum recomendou o uso desse esquema para pegar os dados de uma coluna do SQL e trazer ao select. Porém, quando envio o formulário o que está sendo enviado é o id_projeto e não o nome_projeto. Estou usando o método $_POST. Como resolver? (Coloquei as partes relacionadas apenas)

```
$nomeproj = $_POST['tipoProjeto'];

$insert="INSERT INTO despesas(
      nomeProjeto)
    VALUES(
      '$nomeproj')";

<p> <select name="tipoProjeto" id="projeto" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Projeto</option>
        <?php while($prod = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $prod['id_projeto'] ?>"><?php echo $prod['nome_projeto'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    
        </select></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

O que é enviado para o backend é o conteúdo do atributo value dos options. Caso queira passar o nome do projeto, bastaria trocar:

```
<option value="<?php echo $prod['id_projeto'] ?>">
```

por

```
<option value="<?php echo $prod['nome_projeto'] ?>">
```

Porém, algumas coisas estão confusas no seu código. Por que relacionar o nome do projeto a despesa ao invés do id ele? Ainda, prefira usar um nome para o select que traduza o que ele envia de dado. Talvez, ao invés de "tipoProjeto", "projeto".

Comment: É porque isso vai ser algo mostrado na tela em outra página para um adm. Já está criada, mas o que aparece lá era o id do projeto e não o nome.

Comment: Entendi. Fazendo esta troca, vai aparecer o nome lá.